# how do i combine multiple single dimensional arrays into a multi-dimensional arrays which results in a listed display

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

hi im trying to get my code to work but unfortunately im having some troubles combining my arrays together into a list.

i wanted the listed to display something like that :

1.a, 1.b, 1.c, 1.d, 1.e, 2.a, 2.b, 2.c, 2.d, 2.e

each calling the number from array 1 (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,...) and the question from array 2 (i.e. a,b,c,d,e)

but as it is being called i also want to record the responses given for each number and question for example.

1.a response1, 1.b response2, 1.c response1... and so on.

so far i have this code but it just shows me :

```
const int phone_number = 50;

string[] phone_number1;

phone_number1 = new string[phone_number];

const int question = 5;

string[] question1;

question1 = new string[question];

const int answers = phone_number + question;

string[] answer1;

answer1 = new string[answers];
```

> 50 5 55

Comment: You just provided the definitions. Where is the logic? It seems that you are just printing three integers you defined. Also it seems that you haven't read enough programming books.

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of what you want (an example) ... probably something like this

```
        int[] intarr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        char[] chrarr = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
        ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();

        for (int j = 0; j < chrarr.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < intarr.Length; i++)
            {
                alist.Add(intarr[i] + "." + chrarr[j]);
            }
        }
          alist.Sort();

        foreach (string str in alist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```

Outputs:

> 1.a
>   1.b
>   1.c
>   1.d
>   2.a
>   2.b
>   2.c
>   2.d
>   3.a
>   3.b
>   3.c
>   3.d
>   4.a
>   4.b
>   4.c
>   4.d
>   5.a
>   5.b
>   5.c
>   5.d

Answer (score 0):

Make three arrays, pseudo-code:

```
string[] num;
string[] que;
string[] res;
```

Put them in a fourth array

```
Object[] acc = {num, que, res};
```

Put this into the ArrayList that you are maintaining.

```
lsit.Add(acc);
```

This is just an idea, you should avoid using Object arrays, and if allowed, the best way is to create a class for these properties and save them in list.